# Executing task only on the first run on each host

Tags: ansible

I'm new to ansible and I would like to run some tasks only once. Not once per every run but only once and then never. In puppet I used file placeholders for that, similar to ansible "creates".

What is the best practice for my use case?

If I should use the "creates" method, which folder should be safe to use?

For example I would like to install letsencrypt on host where the first step is to update snap. I don't want to refresh snap every run so I would like to run it only before letsencrypt install.

```
- name: Update snap
      command: snap install core && snap refresh core
      args:
        creates: /usr/local/ansible/placeholders/.update-snap
      become: true
```

Comment: For something like managing [`snap:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/general/snap_module.html), I would expect interrogating the state of the system is the correct way, and not leaving sentinel files on the filesystem as a replacement for that. That said, I don't have hands on experience with snaps -- does the provided module not do what you want?

Comment: module for snap doesnt support it and it is recommended to use command or shell. atleast in my 2.9 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the ansible modules are made to be idempotent, which means that they will perform action only when needed.

`shell`, `script` and `command` are the exception as ansible cannot know if action needs to be performed, and that's why there is the `creates` parameter to add idempotency.

That's why before writing a `shell` task you should check if there is not already an ansible module that could perform your task. There are almost 3000 base modules and with new versions of ansible you can get new community-provided modules through collections in Ansible Galaxy.

In your specific case, the `snap` module (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/general/snap_module.html) may be enough:

```yaml
- name: Update snap
  snap:
    name: core
  become: true
```

It will install the `core` snap if it's not already installed, and do nothing otherwise.

If it's not enough, you can implement yourself idempotency by creating a task querying snap to check the presence of `core` with it's version (add a `changed_when: False` as it's a task not doing any changes) and then launching the install/update depending on the query result (with a `when` condition).

If there is no way to do that, then you can fallback to using the `creates`. If the command executed already creates a specific file that presence can be used to know if it was already executed, better to reference this one. Else you need to create your own marker file in the `shell`. As it's a last option solution, there is no convention of where this marker file should be, so up to you to create your own (the one you propose looks good, even if the file name could be more specific and include the snap name in case you should use the same trick for other snaps).

Comment: Your ansible code doesn't execute command "snap refresh core". It only checks if it is installed and if it is not, installs it. Also I would like to avoid community modules where I need to run only few tasks because in puppet, several community modules were abandoned.

Comment: From https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues/652 a refresh is useless as it's automatically refreshed on regular basis. So install should be enough.

Comment: refresh is not useless if you have new host on which you want to run ansible for the first time to configure it.

Comment: By using the module `snap`: on any execution (first one or subsequent ones), if the `core` snap is not installed (or was removed for some reason, BTW), it will be installed with (from what I understand) latest version of the snap, and then snapd will deal with regular refresh without ansible. Am I missing something?